# Scalar multiplied with cross product of two vectors

Tags: vectors

Look at the following equation: $$ a[\vec{b}\ \times \ \vec{c}] = \vec{b} \ \times \ a\vec{c}$$

How is the above equation true?

Note - I am a beginner to vectors. I am just introduced to vectors so that I can use it in basic physics problems.

It was used in angular momentum. The following was given in the book: $$ m[\vec{r}\ \times \ \vec{a}] = \vec{r} \ \times \ m\vec{a} = \vec{\tau}$$

Comment: Look at the formula for $b \times c$.

Comment: Both sides of the equation have the same direction and magnitude

Comment: Is that a formula? Does it have a proof?

Comment: @Kaushik: Yes, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation